# How to keep the ellipse position fixed regardless of the transformations?

Tags: wpf, xaml, transformation

I have an ellipse which is placed on the bottom of the canvas in WPF. I apply some transformations to the canvas and the ellipse is disappeared. I am new to the world of WPF and transformations. Please guide.

My XAML is as follows:

```
<Grid>
      <Canvas Width="200" Height="200" Background="LightBlue">
         <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
               <MatrixTransform>
                  <MatrixTransform.Matrix>
                     <Matrix M11="45.062" M22="-45.062" OffsetX="13.625" OffsetY="131.499" />
                  </MatrixTransform.Matrix>
               </MatrixTransform>
            </TransformGroup>
         </Canvas.RenderTransform>
         <Ellipse Canvas.ZIndex="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Left="0" Fill="Red" />
      </Canvas>
   </Grid>
```

Comment: It's all explained in detail in the [Transforms Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms750596.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: @Clemens, yes I have gone through the article, I did not get clear direction through that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the Ellipse not to transform, remove it from the Canvas.  Since it's a child of the Canvas, which has a transform, it will transform as well.  Or, you could apply a transform to the Ellipse to cancel out the parent Transform, but that's much more work than you need to do.

Comment: I want the ellipse to be in the exact same position on the canvas even after the transformation. Is it possible for me to keep it outside and still make it transform in the same position on the canvas?

Comment: You can always put your ellipse into a separate container so that it is "in front" of the canvas with the transformation.  That way, your canvas can transform while your ellipse stays in the same position.